# how to update the ui on different thread that use concurrent collection

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My application need to run 8 different timers ( each timer is an object )  - and each time one of the timers is update ( on each timer object that is CountDownTimer that evrey X seconds send pulse that update the time object ) the ui need to be update also.

So, I have some queue that i hold on the ui class ( mainActivity ) that need to store the relevant object until it will update the ui.

1. How to create cocurrent queue on java android
2. How can i update the ui on some different thread and not create some 'freeze' when the ui element are update from the queue

Comment: post the code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Vector` for thread safe list.
You cannot update UI on some different thread apart from the main thread, this is against Android threading ecosystem, where main thread keeps on listening for events, messages and process same

There are various approaches for same

`[runOnUiThread][1]`, `[Handlers][1]` and you can find many more

e.g.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //perform some UI operation here..
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: [runOnUiThread][1], [Handlers][1] and you can find many more

??/